# My Ubuntu is suffering from ACPI errors. Also is not loading

Tags: grub2, acpi, linux-headers

after update, [i am getting this error every time i turn on my Laptop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czFH1.jpg)
After that i get black screen and it loads nothing for hours...

Also, if i press SHIFT to enter GRUB menu [I get several versions of Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5570.jpg) and only in case i choose Ubuntu, With Linux 5.3.0-42-generic, i can't load my system.
what to do ?

Comment: Did this start after installing the rc5 version of kernel 5.6.0? Not a good idea. Can you boot to the -40 kernel? But not the -42 kernel? Do you have good backups of your important data... as I might recommend a Ubuntu reinstall.

Comment: I can not run 050600rc but can run 42. Maybe i run some wrong command, but would like to know if i can restore system without reinstall, to avoid files backup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- boot to the -42 or -40 kernel
- open `terminal`

`dpkg -l linux-* | grep ii | grep 5.6.0` # show you the kernel 5.6.0 files

Should give you about 5 lines, all related to kernel 5.6.0

`sudo apt-get purge enter_one_filename_here` # do this for each of the 5 filenames

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Update #1:**

MSI MS-16GD (CX61 2PC)

To try and eliminate the ACPI errors, we'll need to update your BIOS.

Make sure you have good backups before updating the BIOS.

You have BIOS E16GDIMS.50O. Current BIOS is E16GDIMS.60Q and can be downloaded from [here.](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/CX61-2PC)

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili Good news! No more rc software, ok :-)

Comment: Yea, but there is ACPI errors at boot, again. Should i just ignore it ?

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili Let's quickly check your BIOS version. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: it's E16GDIMS.50O

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili ...and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: Sorry !
MSI MS-16GD

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili Is there another model #, that starts with CX or GP? I can't find MS-16GD at the web site.

Comment: Yes, it should be CX61

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili getting close... something comes after the CX61

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili if you're having a hard time finding that, edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -t 1,2`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105706/discussion-between-aleko-gharibashvili-and-heynnema).

Comment: @AlekoGharibashvili How did the BIOS update go?